# Localization support in DataGridView's Designer

Tags: c#, datagridview, localization, windows-forms-designer, smart-tags

Is there any support to change the Designer Action Items in MS DataGridView based on current culture? Localization for DesignerAction items added in SmartTag panel for DataGridView as below,

[image]

Does the above Designer Action Panel supports location or Can we build our own Custom Controls with DesignerActionList with Localization?

If localization can be supported, please share me how to enable the support.

Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: It seems resource manager reads neutral resources at design-time regardless of current UI thread.